# How to get the http://www.blbah.com part of the url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My url on a page is like:

```
http://www.example.com/dir1/file.html?a=1
```

I need to extract:

```
http://www.example.com
```

how can I do this in javascript?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `window.location` is an object with useful properties for this, details in [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/etimahash:).

For that JSBin URL (http://jsbin.com/etima), here's what you see (with some irrelevancies removed):

- `href`: http://jsbin.com/etima
- `protocol`: http:
- `hostname`: jsbin.com
- `host`: jsbin.com
- `port`:
- `pathname`: /etima
- `search`:
- `hash`:

So basically, combine the `protocol`, the `hostname`, and the `port` if any:

```
var loc, result;
loc = window.location;
result = loc.protocol + "//" + loc.hostname;
if (loc.port) {
    result += ":" + loc.port;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.location.protocol + '//'+document.domain
```

Comment: ...which will break if there's ever a port specified. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might find http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri / http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/ interesting